# What is correct way get an Object Instance in ConfigureServices itself?

Tags: c#, .net-core

With-in `ConfigureServices` method, what is right way of retrieving object instance?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<SERVICES.Core.IAuthService, SERVICES.Core.AuthService>();
        //.......

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var authService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthService>();
    }
```

**EDIT:** Why?: Microsoft doesn't recommend us to use this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ASP0000

Comment: `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SERVICES.Core.IAuthService>();`

Comment: `var authService = serviceProvider.GetService<SERVICES.Core.IAuthService>();` I use this in my project.

Comment: @vsarunov and @Chetan that's for `IServiceProvider` not `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: And why you need it? It should be injected to the object which needs it

Comment: Why would you wanna do this though? I have done it before and fix it to do proper injection

Comment: Depending on what you're using those services for (is it to select more services to register?) I would suggest using the overloads of Add...() that take `Func<IServiceProvider, T>`. Then you can resolve services at the point the service is built and make decisions there just-in-time, rather than on the start-up path itself and build the container multiple times.

Comment: @Selvin, I know its anti-pattern, on why I need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547805/what-is-alternative-of-addopenidconnect-middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a service to register another, you can use a different overload to register it, where you have access to `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IAnotherService>(
    provider =>
    {
        var authService = provider.GetRequiredService<IAuthService>();
        return new AnotherServiceImplementation(authService);
    }
);
```

If you need a service to configure something, you can implement an `IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>`.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>, ConfigureMyOptions>();
```

```cs
class ConfigureMyOptions: IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>
{
    private IAuthService _authService; // inject a service
    private IConfiguration _configuration; // a configuration
    private SomeOptions _someOptions; // an option

    public ConfigureMyOptions(IAuthService authService, IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<SomeOptions> someOptions)
    {
        _authService = authService;
        _configuration = configuration;
        _someOptions = someOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Configure(MyOptions options)
    {
        // use _authService
        var something = _authService.GetSomething();
        _configuration.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing good overload, but the use-case is bit tricky than using the overload.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547805/what-is-alternative-of-addopenidconnect-middleware

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my project:

`var authService = serviceProvider.GetService<SERVICES.Core.IAuthService>();`

The difference between `GetRequiredService<T>` and `GetService<T>`
Is that `GetRequiredService<T>` throws an exception if no service is found for the type `T`. While the `GetService<T>` returns null.

If you are ok to such a deal breaker use the first one, if you want to verify then you can use the second and check for `null` case. Depends on your case, I prefer the later in order to verify, though in most cases you would get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: that's for `IServiceProvider` not `IServiceCollection`. OP asks about resolving a service **inside** `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @abdusco Look clearly at the example the OP provided.